# CopyFile docx makes hidden conversion to doc

Tags: delphi, winapi, docx

i got a Delphi 7 program which has to copy a docx file. I'm using the Windows API [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. The problem is that this function seems to make a hidden conversion to the older doc format. 
First thing: the file size increases after the copy. 
Second: When opening the file in Office 2007 i got an error message stating that: *Check your permissions to the document or disk, check free disk space*.

And than the strange thing: if i change in TotalCommander the extension of the copied file from docx to doc it opens normally. So it seems to make a hidden conversion dont know why.

Tested on two different computers. Both Win XP Prof SP3, Office 2007 Prof Plus SP2

Any ideas?

Function body is below:

```
function  TDlgNowySzablon.PobierzPlikNaDoc() : string;
var
  openDlg : TOpenDialog;
begin
  Result:='';
  openDlg:=TOpenDialog.Create(self);
  openDlg.Filter:='Dokumenty Microsoft Word (*.doc;*docx)|*.doc;*.docx';

  if openDlg.Execute then begin
    Result := IObsSzab.GetTempFullFileName( ExtractFileExt(openDlg.FileName) );
    if not CopyFile(PChar(openDlg.FileName),PChar(Result),true) then begin
      Result:='';
    end;
  end;

  openDlg.Free;
end;
```

Comment: "First thing: the file size increases after the copy." Are you really sure that happens?

Comment: The Windows `CopyFile` function doesn't convert Microsoft Word DOCX files to DOC. It has nothing to do with Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your code as follows:

```
Result := IObsSzab.GetTempFullFileName('.tmp');
Result := ChangeFileExt(Result, ExtractFileExt(openDlg.FileName));
```

I think your `GetTempFullFileName` function is truncating .docx to .doc.  It's all guesswork though!

The `CopyFile` function does not modify the contents of the file.

Comment: ChangeFileExt did not change my file extension, dont know why. But when i renamed manually the .tmp to .docx it opened ok. So i think i can give here an Accept and the rest i should fix by myself. Thank you.

Comment: Anyway i still would like to know why when copying the target file extension matters. Strange ...

Comment: @Robert Well, the lpNewFileName parameter of CopyFile is just the full name of the destination file. It can have any extension you like. The file contents are unaffected. Your temp file function is probably based on Windows.GetTempFileName which returns 8.3 file names and so truncates your .docx to .doc.